# DataGridView .net Custom Sorting Column Date

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

Please have a look on these columns which is containing a specific date (which is not international based):

[image: Tanggal Buat & Tanggal Lahir]

The usual sorting (default) works with a main problem, such as **its orders' are not properly ordered as the trully date.**

**Can anyone give a bit clue for solving this current case?**

I looked around for this topic but found **2 only especially for Ascending & Descending normal (numerical / string values)**. any clue?

**Note:**

**1) All of my data rows are added manually so it's not a db sync datasource.**

the way i added is with the following Source Code:

[image: Added Manually to the DataGridView]

Comment: Are you adding the Date values as a `Date` object or as a `String` object? I think they can be added as `Date` objects and then formatted for display how ever you want. The sorting should then work as expected.

Comment: no, the value is String object.

Comment: Before adding to the DataGridView can the Strings be converted to Dates? This would solve your problem immediately

Comment: I would make the date column actual DateTime type so when users type in the date you make sure it is valid.  You could add a DateTime Picker to allow users to select the date.  A string date will not sort properly.   You need to add to the sort event a parser to convert to  DateTime.

Comment: NEVER, EVER store dates as text.  The data should be binary dates, i.e. type `DateTime` in VB, and then formatted as desired by the grid by setting the `DefaultCellStyle.Format` of that column.  When the data is sorted, it will be sorted by the actual values, not what is displayed in the cells. If there's a problem with the sorting it's because you have broken the data.

Comment: yes i make the String converted become DateTime but... once it is added to datagrid it still not working as expected. please check my 2nd screenshot above. @JayV.

Comment: @gumuruh based on the screen shot, you are still changing the `DateTime` object to a `String`. You should change your array declaration to `Dim row As Object() = New Object() {...}`

Comment: alright problem solved! @JayV you're super! ....